# QGIS plugin problem, can't reach objects in a Qt-based Stacked Widget

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt, qt-designer

I am creating a plugin for QGIS but am having trouble with the Qt components. I have used Plugin Builder and Qt designer to create all necessary files for the plugin.
I want to use a QStackedWidget inside my QDialog and I can open the dialog just fine when I don't try to access the "pages" (or widgets) of the stacked widget. But I am getting an error when trying to reach the pages/objects located inside the pages of a stacked widget from my code.

Simple code example:

```
def __init__(self, iface):

    self.dlg = Dialog() 
    self.stackedWidget = self.dlg.stackedWidget
    self.dlg.stackedWidget.page.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func)

def func(self):
    :code that does some stuff:
```

Returns the error:

> AttributeError: 'QStackedWidget' object has no attribute 'page'

Similarly if I try to work with just a stacked widget not inside a QDialog (again opens just fine without the code that causes errors) I get the same kind of error.

Code Example:

```
def __init__(self, iface):

    self.stackedWidget = StackedWidget() 
    self.page = self.stackedWidget.page
    self.page.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func)

def func(self):
    :code that does some stuff:
```

Returns the error:

> AttributeError: 'QWidget' object has no attribute 'pushButton'

What am I doing wrong or what is causing the error?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `page` attribute on the QStackWidget object.  Here are all the methods that it has: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html

What you need to do get the widget is call the widget function:

`widget = self.stackedWidget.widget(index)`

where `index` is the page index of the widget.